# How can I convert a BigInteger String to an ASCII String?

Tags: java, string

I have the two inverse inverse functions:

```
public static BigInteger stringToBig(String message) {      
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : message.toCharArray()) {
        sb.append((int)c);
    }

    return new BigInteger(sb.toString());
}

public static String bigStringToString(String string) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int x = (string.length() % 3 - 3) % 3; x < string.length(); x += 3) {
        int chr = Integer.parseInt(string.substring(Math.max(x, 0), x + 3));
        result.append(Character.toString((char) (chr)));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

My goal is to take the string from

> "This is my message"

Convert it to `"8410410511532105115321091213210910111511597103101"`

and then convert it back to `"This is my message"`

I've tried the following but get `"????is?[ÕÒ?o??ge"` back as an output from `bigStringToString`

```
String text = String.valueOf(stringToBig("This is my message"));
System.out.println(text);
System.out.println(bigStringToString(text));
```

What's wrong with my conversion back?

Comment: Your transform isn't reversible. The digits 123 could be 1 then 2 then 3, or it could be 12 and 3, or 1 and 23, or literally 123.

Comment: What makes you think `char` is ASCII? It's actually UTF-16.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ah, yup

Comment: … and the decimal digits that [Character.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_VALUE) requires could be … or 65535. Try "" for the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current transform isn't reversible, instead you can use the `byte[]` from `String.getBytes()` directly. And don't forget to specify an encoding. Something like,

```
String s = "This is my message";
try {
    byte[] enc = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
    BigInteger val = new BigInteger(enc);
    System.out.println(val);
    System.out.println(new String(val.toByteArray(), "UTF-8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Outputs

```
7352961551138726160548009928799764296591205
This is my message
```

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by others, you are not accounting for the different lengths of integers.  Since you assume all characters are ascii and have length 3, you can use this when constructing the string for the BigInteger:

```
 sb.append(String.format("%03d", (int) c));
```